# How to turn off logstash schedule and start it manually?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to make a simple task using logstash. I want from it to get all my data from SQL database, filter it and save it to elasticsearch, then my logstash should shutdown ( no more putting data to elasticsearch, I dont want from it to perform same task over some schedule ).

Is there any way how can I do it ?

I am newbie to logstash so thank you for any help.

Comment: Just don't add the `schedule` parameter :-)

Comment: @Val thank you, pretty easy :D.